# Tomcat WatchedResource / auto-deploy ineffective?

Tags: debian, tomcat

My task involves deploying a Java web application into a Tomcat 6.0.35 instance running on Debian Squeeze. As such, Tomcat is installed from package sources and the web application is deployed from a custom .deb package that puts the .war file into a directory below `/opt` and registers it with Tomcat by dropping a context XML (let's call it `my-app.xml`) into `/etc/tomcat6/Catalina/localhost/`. This works fine for the initial .deb install where the application is picked up by Tomcat's auto deployment mechanism and unpacked into `/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/`.

When re-installing a newer version of the .deb, Tomcat will not update the application, though. It will only detect a change if I manually execute a

```
touch /etc/tomcat6/Catalina/localhost/my-app.xml
```

Even restarting Tomcat without touching `my-app.xml` has no effect.

`my-app.xml` looks like this:

```
<Context path="/my-app" docBase="/opt/my-app/my-app.war">
    <WatchedResource>/opt/my-app/my-app.war</WatchedResource>
</Context>
```

IMHO, this should watch for changes of the .war (which changes when I install the updated .deb).

Autodeploy is turned on in `server.xml`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `touch` line into the post-install script of your `deb` file

Comment: I would have hoped to be able to solve this by configuration, but sure, this will do as a workaround.